# PHP Not Picking Up Post Data from jQuery AJAX Form Submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, submit

I have a form with a submit button like this:

```
<form action="?edit-form" method="post" class="addEdit">
    <input type="submit" name="delete-image" value="Delete Image">
</form>
```

My jQuery AJAX is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $('form.addEdit').attr('action'),
    type: $('form.addEdit').attr('method'),
    data: $('form.addEdit').serialize(),
    success: function(html) { }
});
```

In my PHP, I am unable to pick up that $_POST['delete-image'] isset() eventhough the submit button that sent the form is named "delete-image".

```
if (isset($_POST['delete-image'])) {
}
```

"delete-image" should be set since that was the submit button I clicked. Why is PHP not picking up this posted varaible from this AJAX submit?

Comment: What does `print_r($_POST)` in your php script give you?

Comment: Is the URL "?edit-form" valid?

Comment: Matt, yes, it's short for "index.php?edit-form." I tried that URL but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery documenation here: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/
Only succesful control are serialized, please see the documentation below:

> Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button. For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string, the element must have a name attribute. Values from checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox") are included only if they are checked. Data from file select elements is not serialized.

So submit buttn won't serialize through jQuery.serialize() function. The work around is you can add hidden input, and it will serialized.

**UPDATE:**
You need to change the form submit ajax to bind the button click. and in ajax request you can add the button value manually. Below is my code that is working.

```
$( "#delImage" ).click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $form = $(this).parent('form');
    $btnid = $(this).attr('name');
    $btnval = $(this).attr('value');


    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        data: { "btnid" : $btnid, "btnval": $btnval, "form-data": $form.serialize() },
        success: function(html) {
            console.log(html);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ivan, good information. However, it's critical that I perform this AJAX when this specific button is clicked. Since the input submit button has a name "delete-image" isn't there some way that I can determine the form was submitted when this button was clicked?

Comment: @GTSJoe You could add a hidden input with a name of `delete-image` ?

Comment: I can't add a hidden input field because I have two submit buttons in this form. So if a user clicked on the other button, the hidden input would be submitted when that button was clicked, too. I need to be able to pass the data in <input type="submit" name="delete-image" value="Delete Image"> only when that button is clicked, that's why it's crucial I avoid a hidden field.

Comment: @Ivan: yes it does work, but now the page reloads like a regular submit. event.preventDefault(); is supposed to stop this but it doesn't. Why? The page shouldn't reload for an AJAX request.

Comment: Probably there is an error in your jQuery script. please see from the chrome console for more details.

Comment: Ivan thanks for your help, it's working but how do I check if the variable isset in PHP? I was using: if (isset($_POST['delete-image'])) {}. Which variable name should I pass to isset()?

Comment: You can check through if($_POST['btnval'] == 'delete-image')

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the page to reload when the button is been click then just use the simple way of sending ajax call:

```
var mydata = $('form.addEdit').serialize();
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url: 'file.php',
data: mydata,
dataType:'json',
success: function(responseText){
// enter code here
 });
}
});
```

simply having your form without those elements

```
<form class="addEdit">
<input type="submit" name="delete-image" value="Delete Image">
</form>
```